# sails lift fails when performing alter auto-migration strategy by trying to do select with IN() without ids in IN()

Tags: sails.js, waterline

When lifting sails, I get a fatal error when it is trying to perform alter auto-migration strategy. Error message was not helpful and I traced to find the things that sails lift was performing that caused the error. These are the last queries that are executed (look at the last query).

```
DESCRIBE `class`
SHOW INDEX FROM `class`;
SELECT `class`.`name`, `class`.`schoolFk`, `class`.`id`, `class`.`createdAt`, `class`.`updatedAt` FROM `class`
DROP TABLE `class`
DESCRIBE `class`
CREATE TABLE `class` (`name` VARCHAR(50) , `schoolFk` INT , `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `createdAt` DATETIME , `updatedAt` DATETIME )
DESCRIBE `class`
SHOW INDEX FROM `class`;
INSERT INTO `class` (`class`.`name`, `class`.`schoolFk`, `class`.`id`, `class`.`createdAt`, `class`.
`updatedAt`) VALUES ('9 N', 1, 7, '2014-08-16 22:35:07', '2014-08-16 22:35:07');
INSERT INTO `class` (`class`.`name`, `class`.`schoolFk`, `class`.`id`, `class`.`createdAt`, `class`.
`updatedAt`) VALUES ('9M', 1, 9, '2014-08-16 23:07:53', '2014-08-16 23:07:53');
INSERT INTO `class` (`class`.`name`, `class`.`schoolFk`, `class`.`id`, `class`.`createdAt`, `class`.
`updatedAt`) VALUES ('9 C', 1, 5, '2014-08-16 22:07:01', '2014-08-16 22:07:01');
INSERT INTO `class` (`class`.`name`, `class`.`schoolFk`, `class`.`id`, `class`.`createdAt`, `class`.
`updatedAt`) VALUES ('9 P', 1, 8, '2014-08-16 22:40:29', '2014-08-16 22:40:29');

SELECT * FROM `class` WHERE `id` IN (7,9,5,8);

DESCRIBE `exam`
SHOW INDEX FROM `exam`;
SELECT `exam`.`academicYear`, `exam`.`schoolFk`, `exam`.`classFk`, `exam`.`term`, `exam`.`examNo`, `exam`.`lesson`, `exam`.`examTopics`, `exam`.`userFk`, `exam`.`id`, `exam`.`createdAt`, `exam`.`updatedAt` FROM `exam`
DROP TABLE `exam`
DESCRIBE `exam`
CREATE TABLE `exam` (`academicYear` VARCHAR(20) , `schoolFk` INT , `classFk` INT , `term` VARCHAR(50) , `examNo` VARCHAR(50) , `lesson` VARCHAR(255) , `examTopics` LONGTEXT , `userFk` INT , `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, `createdAt` DATETIME , `updatedAt` DATETIME )
DESCRIBE `exam`
SHOW INDEX FROM `exam`;
SELECT * FROM `exam` WHERE `id` IN ();
```

In last query, it is trying to do a select with IN() without supplying any values (That table is empty and apparently it couldnt find any ids to put in there like it is doing in class table query above)

My question is why it is trying to do so if the table is empty (no insertions seen above for exam table) and how can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgres?  Which version of Sails are you on?

Comment: Sails v0.10.4 and I am using MySQL

Comment: Can you post your models so we can go ahead and recreate the process.

Comment: I am a startup on stealth mode right now and I am really hesitant about posting the models at this stage -- maybe a month later or so (it can help one to reverse engineer the idea/problem -- sorry about the paranoia). Is there any other way that I can help?

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by putting some data in the `exam` table but couldn't find out why sails was trying to do IN() without any parameters when the table is empty.